R model breaks when as.formula() used outside of the parent function
I am trying to fit a coxph model inside a function like so:
data(cancer, package="survival") # Import `mgus2` data
ndata <- expand.grid(sex=c("F", "M"), age=c(60, 80))

# Fit Cox PH model and run survfit
fit_cox <- function(df) {
    msfit <- coxph(Surv(futime, death) ~ sex + age, data=df, id=id)
    mssurv <- survfit(msfit, newdata=ndata)
}

fit_cox(mgus2)

The problem occurs if I want to define the formula Surv(futime, death) ~ sex + age as a string and use as.formula() to pass it to my model.
If the call to as.formula is outside the fit_cox function, then the call to survfit breaks:
my_formula <- as.formula("Surv(futime, death) ~ sex + age")

# Fit Cox PH model and run survfit
fit_cox <- function(df) {
    msfit <- coxph(my_formula, data=df, id=id)
    mssurv <- survfit(msfit, newdata=ndata)
}

> fit_cox(mgus2)
> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(futime, death) ~ sex + age,  : 
> 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list

The issue does not occur when the call to as.formula is moved into the fit_cox function.
fit_cox <- function(df) {
    my_formula <- as.formula("Surv(futime, death) ~ sex + age") # Moved this inside
    msfit <- coxph(my_formula, data=df, id=id)
    mssurv <- survfit(msfit, newdata=ndata)
}

> fit_cox(mgus2)
> # Successful

I am wondering whether this is not a package-specific issue to do with the survival package that implements coxph and survfit. Instead, it might have something to do with the as.formula call.
What difference does it make having it be inside the function rather than outside?

This is a general "feature" of the way that model frame construction is often done in R. Here is the call stack at the moment when we get in trouble:
where 1: model.frame.coxph(object)
where 2: stats::model.frame(object)
where 3: survfit.coxph(msfit, newdata = ndata)
where 4 at #3: survfit(msfit, newdata = ndata)
where 5: fit_cox(mgus2)

And this is the line where the error is thrown:
mf <- eval(temp, environment(formula$terms), parent.frame())


temp is the unevaluated model frame call, which the package has modified for its purposes:

stats::model.frame(formula = Surv(futime, death) ~ sex + age, 
    data = df, id = id, xlev = list(sex = c("F", "M")))


parent.frame() is the environment from which the current function was called, i.e. the environment of stats::model.frame()  (see the call stack above)
environment(formula$terms) is the environment in which the formula was created, which is typically where R assumes it can find everything referred to in the formula (if not in the parent frame)

When the formula is created in an environment where the new data (df) can't be found, you get this problem.
I haven't tested it, but adding
assign("df", df, environment(my_formula))

to your function would probably resolve the problem.

What great debugging, thanks! Based on that, one could also set the formula environment to the function environment (which has df in it) by adding environment(my_formula) <- environment() as the first line of the function.

It's tricky to explain why this happens and I'm not quite sure I have a handle on exactly what's going on here, but one solution is to use do.call to run the function like this:
fit_cox <- function(df) {
  msfit <- do.call("coxph", list(formula=my_formula, 
                                 data=substitute(df), 
                                 id=as.name("id")))
  mssurv <- survfit(msfit, newdata=ndata)
  mssurv
}

The issue has something to do with how the call is constructed and where the variables in it are stored; in your function the call has your intermediate variables (my_formula and df) in it:
do_cox1 <- function(df) {
  coxph(my_formula, data=df, id=id)
}
do_cox1(mgus2)
# Call:
# coxph(formula = my_formula, data = df, id = id)

But if one uses do.call, which computes the values of variables before constructing the call, you can get the actual values of the variables and the data set. Use substitute to get the name of the data variable and as.name to create a variable for id.
do_cox2 <- function(df) {
  do.call("coxph", list(formula=my_formula, 
                        data=substitute(df), 
                        id=as.name("id")))
}
do_cox2(mgus2)
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(futime, death) ~ sex + age, data = mgus2, id = id)

See this answer for another example.
See Ben Bolker's answer for an explanation of what's happening, but based on that, the reason this works is that the model is now fit using mgus2 which is in the global environment, and that's the same environment the formula was built in.

Thank you. Can you explain the purpose of the call to substitute?

"substitute() substitutes the symbol with the expression that was given as an argument." See this answer.

The problem is that the OP was creating a formula outside the calling function and therefore had the incorrect environment. Formula objects that are evaluated inside the coxph call will see the data object, but those created outside will have no idea what data object was intended. Your do.call approach does result in the construction of the formula with the correct attached environment.
